# Designing database tables

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am implementing a questionnaire application that has different type of questions and answers. My goal is to create database tables in an efficient way so that they will be scalable.

Comment: Can you change your DBMS I, if you can, I suggest to you take a look at Array Data Type, on Postgresql.
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html
I don't know all your requirements but may be very smart idea use that feature.
With this feature:
You just have only 1 table and 2 columns.
You don't waste disk space.
Think about that.

Answer (score 1):

Create one table for questions and one table for answers, then create a foreign key with question id's in the answers table.

Something like:

Question table

```
+---------+-------------+------+---------+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key     | Default | Extra |
+---------+-------------+------+---------+---------+-------+
| q_id    | int         | NO   | PRIMARY | NULL    |       |
| question| varchar(20) | NO   |         | NULL    |       |
+---------+-------------+------+---------+---------+-------+
```

Answer table

```
+---------+-------------+------+---------+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key     | Default | Extra |
+---------+-------------+------+---------+---------+-------+
| a_id    | int         | NO   | PRIMARY | NULL    |       |
| q_id    | int         | NO   | FOREIGN | NULL    |       |
| answer  | varchar(20) | NO   |         | NULL    |       |
+---------+-------------+------+---------+---------+-------+
```

Comment: could you explain a bit more?

Comment: Joe is also proposing creating a standalone table to connect multiple questions to an answer as well as the other way.

Comment: It's one question, many answers.  The classic one-to-many with a foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I developed a similar system and did a `questions (id, question_text)` table and an `answers (id, answer_text)` table, plus a `question2answer (question_id | answer_id | correct )` table with a unique index on (question_id, answer_id) to avoid inserting the same answer to the same question twice. 'correct' is a true| false flag to signify that the answer is correct for that question for scoring purposes.

That way if you want to add an answer to a question later on you just insert the answer in the answers table and map it to the question in the question2answer.

This also allows you to reutilise answers for more than 1 question. (i.e. you don't have to put a 'yes' and a 'no' a million times in the database, you just map the existing answer id for 'yes' to the new question that allows a yes answer.